# Highlighting the contents of a cell in a dataframe in pandas within a value range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When looking at my dataframe, I want to highlight all contents of cells that have a value greater than 8.5. The problem is, I have year ranges identifying year/month as the columns/rows. When I apply the highlight to the values above 8.5, I get the years highlighted as well. I've tried logic in order to isolate the dates, but that resulted in error.

Code:

```
def highlight_unemp(number):
x = number > 8.5
print(['background-color: red' if i else '' for i in x])
return ['background-color: red' if i else '' for i in x]

df.style.apply(highlight_unemp)
```

The rows of dates are listed from 1936 to 2019, which are getting highlighted.

How can I work around this to highlight only the values above 8.5 yet under... 100?

Thank you!

Comment: if you have small number of columns, then you can exclude the year column as `df.style.apply(highlight_unemp, subset=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col4'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the years to datetimes with

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
```